# sympy: how to use sympy.sympify for two variables?

Tags: python, sympy

How to use sympy.sympify for two or more variables?

This code with one variable works.

```
aa = sympify("4*x**2 + 5*x - 6 > 1 , x > 0.8")
print(solve(aa))

>> (0.838087488839953 < x) & (x < oo)
```

But this code with two variables does not work.

```
aa = sympify("x + y = 8 ,  2x - y < 5 ")
print(solve(aa))

>> sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse 'x + y = 8 ,  2x - y < 5 '' 
failed, because of exception being raised:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

I would like to solve equations or inequalities involving two or more variables with 'string' input like "4*x**2 + 5*x - 6 > 1 , x > 0.8" instead of sympy's symbols. Is it possible to solve linear equations with two variables by sympy's sympify?

Comment: Playing around with your problem line I find `sympify("x + y = 8")` produces the syntax error.  `sympy` intro talks a lot about the '=' gotcha.   '2x' in the second expression is also a problem,  "2*x-y<5" parses ok.  It's not the two variables that's giving the syntax error.

Comment: Thanks hpaulj. But I am still unable to use sympy to solve multivariate inequalities, and would use the PuLP package for multivariate inequalities.